# How do I bring the privacy request popup to the fore? A pop-up window when I reinstall the app is covered by a white screen

Tags: ios, authorization, cllocationmanager, swift5

My app uses location data from the iPhone. For this purpose, the data protection data is requested when the app is started - it works. However, if I delete the app from the iPhone for a new test and restart the debugger, the display on the iPhone / iPad remains on a white screen and the debugger generates an error because there is no location data. The iPhone doesn't ask what kind of permission to give. The query is only displayed when I close the app on the iPhone (not with or in the debugger). Why - and what's going on? Does anyone know a solution?

If I close the app and the blank screen disappears, the popup becomes visible. If I then select "AuthorizedAlways" or "AuthorizedWhenInUse" (in the request popup), the app will run as desired ... Why is the query being put in the background or why is the query being covered by a blank white screen and how can I get around this? Everything works when the location query has been answered. But it is not displayed! or is covered by the white screen.

here a logger output up to the point at which the debugger terminates: 0 --- AppDelegate: application (_: didFinishLaunchingWithOptions:)>)

1 --- Observable: init (value:)>)

2 --- Brand: init ()>) 2020-10-18 09: 23: 02.559857 + 0200 Observer2 [2003: 698275] Metal API Validation Enabled

3 --- ViewController1: viewDidLoad ()>)

4 --- ViewController1: setUpLocationManager ()>)

5 --- ViewController1: checkLocationAuthorization ()>)

AuthorizationStatus (): 0

Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file Observer2 / ViewController1.swift, line 143 2020-10-18 09: 23: 15.747456 + 0200 Observer2 [2003: 698275] Fatal error: Unexpectedly found nil while unwrapping an Optional value: file Observer2 / ViewController1.swift, line 143

```
//---------------------------------------------
override
func viewDidLoad() {

    super.viewDidLoad()

    setUpLocationManager()
    checkLocationServices() /// <----
    setUpMapView()
    checkLocationAuthorization()
    /// ....
}

/// ....

func checkLocationAuthorization() {
    
    if locationManager?.location == nil {
        locationManager = CLLocationManager()
        
        locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
        locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
    }

    startAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()

    switch startAuthorizationStatus! {
    case .authorizedWhenInUse:      /// = 4
    /// do Map Stuff
    //                startTrackingUserLocation()
        break
    case .denied:
        /// show alert instructing them how to turn on permissions
        break
    case .notDetermined:            /// = 0
        locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
        
        if startAuthorizationStatus == .notDetermined {
            locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization()
            
            startAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
        }
        break
    case .restricted:               /// = 1
        /// show alert instructing them know what's up
        break
    case .authorizedAlways:
    //                startTrackingUserLocation() /// = 3
        break
    default:
        print("unknown Switch case")
    break
    }   /// switch
}
```

Comment: What is line 143 of your view controller?  I'm would. It recommend not requesting location permission in `viewDidLoad`. `viewDidAppear` would be a better choice. Your permission request code is all over the place. Just request it one place and handle the delegate callback to determine your location permission

Comment: Also, do you need always or when in use? Ask for what you need, not both.

Comment: line 138 ... 144:
(138)        startAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
(139)        print("AuthorizationStatus(): \(startAuthorizationStatus!.rawValue)")
(140)
(141)        locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
(142)
(143)        print("locationManager.latitude  \(locationManager!.location!.coordinate.latitude)")
(144)        print("locationManager.longitude \(locationManager!.location!.coordinate.longitude)")

Comment: Don't force unwrap or you risk a crash, as you found out. Getting location takes time. You get the location in the `didUpdateLocations` delegate callback.

Comment: (138)        startAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
(139)        print("AuthorizationStatus(): \(startAuthorizationStatus!.rawValue)")
(141)        locationManager!.startUpdatingLocation()
(143)        print("locationManager.latitude  \(locationManager!.location!.coordinate.latitude)")
(144)        print("locationManager.longitude \(locationManager!.location!.coordinate.longitude)")

I placed the query in different places - always the same. It seems to me that I have to make the display invisible on the iPhone.

Comment: Don't use `location!` that will crash if the location is not yet determined or not available. You should only access the location from the delegate callback or by conditionally unwrapping it.

Comment: But that's not the problem! It runs when the authorization has been answered successfully. The problem is: The query is covered by a blank screen!

Comment: So how can I prevent the white screen from covering the display or how do I bring the popup to the foreground?

Comment: Did you move the authorisation code to `viewDidAppear`? Start with a simple call to `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` in `viewDidAppear` and remove all other authorisation requests.

Comment: override func viewDidAppear(_ animated: Bool) {
             super.viewWillAppear(animated) startAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus()
            locationManager!.requestAlwaysAuthorization()
            locationManager!.requestWhenInUseAuthorization() startAuthorizationStatus = CLLocationManager.authorizationStatus() checkLocationAuthorization() 
/// ?? - I see the white screen and only when I close the app do I see the request - as before ...

Comment: You are calling the wrong super method. Make sure you only have a single call to `requestWhenInUseAuthorization` in your entire app.  Don't request always at this time. Make sure that you are only requesting location access in this one place. Comment or remove all other location access requests (use the project search) It sounds like you are calling it before your view controller is presented.

Comment: calling the wrong super method? where - and which one is it and which one would be the right one?
Yes, I only have one function for calling and after authorization has been given - why should you call it again?
The debugger only shows a single call!

Comment: You are calling `super.viewWillAppear()` not `super.viewDidAppear()`. It is better to [edit) your question to add new code rather than adding it in a comment. It doesn't hurt to just ask for permission each time. The prompt is only shown once and you will get a call to your delegate method telling you what the permission is. What you are trying to do is done by every app that uses location, so you have a problem in your code. I am suggesting you simplify your code as the first step to determining where the problem is (or eliminating it)